# jquery ui selectmenu, regarding changing selected items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select-menu

I'm trying to implement a currencty converter which I succeeded but now I'm implementing a button that will change the selected option between two selected menus which means that if in the first menu I have usd selected and in the second menu I have gbp selected then when pressing the button, I want in the first menu to have the gbp selected and in the second menu the usd selected.
I have manage to change the selected option on both menus, but it doesn't display it in the menu itself.
What have I forgot ?

```
 $(function(){
    $('a#switchButton').click(function(){
        var $sel1 = $('#fromCurrency');
        var val1 = $sel1.val();
        var $sel2 = $('#toCurrency');
        var val2 = $sel2.val();
        $sel1.find("option[value='"+val1+"']").attr("selected",false);
        $sel1.find("option[value='"+val2+"']").attr("selected",true);
        $sel2.find("option[value='"+val2+"']").attr("selected",false);
        $sel2.find("option[value='"+val1+"']").attr("selected",true);
    });
});
```

Here is a screen shot, when pressing on the icon in the middle, nothing changes here, but only in the code itself. If I press the icon, I want the usd to appear in "from" and inr in "to".

[image: Screen shot]

[jsfiddle.net example](http://jsfiddle.net/atR6D/3/)

Comment: Could you set up your problem in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/q9jU6/. The only difference here is I put a `return false;` at the end of the click handler to make sure the default anchor action doesn't run.

Comment: @BenLee, It works on simple menus, but I'm using jquery ui selectmenu plugin and in my dropdown select menu I have icons (flag next to each option) and when I press on switch it does switch inside the code, but visually it stays the same

Comment: @Niklas, I've added a screen shot

Comment: @BenLee, I've added a screen shot

Comment: It would be so much easier if you could reproduce the error in jsfiddel.net ... an image doesn't help that much.

Comment: @Niklas, http://jsfiddle.net/atR6D/3/, please notice that the jquery ui selectmenu.css and .js is missing thus you can't see the images

Comment: @Avalon - Did my answer solve it or do you need more help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the *selectmenu()* function has it's own ways of changing values.
Check out a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/atR6D/55/

```
$('#switchButton').click(function(){
    var sel1 = $('#fromCurrency').selectmenu("value");
    var sel2 = $('#toCurrency').selectmenu("value");
    $('#fromCurrency').selectmenu("value", sel2);
    $('#toCurrency').selectmenu("value", sel1);
});
```

It looks like it's making a representation of the select list in `<span>` tags which is why you can't actually change the original select list.

Comment: That worked!, you are genius! I was straggling days with it and couldn't find any answer for it. Thanks alot!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function(){
    $('#switchButton').click(function(){
        var $sel1 = $('#fromCurrency');
        var $sel2 = $('#toCurrency');

        var tmp = $sel2.val();
        $sel2.val($sel1.val());
        $sel1.val(tmp);

    });
});
```

And here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YAQUR/).

Comment: That doesn't work at all, my code does change the selected inside the code, but the UI isn't updated

Comment: @Alon What do you mean the UI is updated? Did you checked the demo?

Comment: I've added a screen shot above, hope it can help

Comment: @Alon OMG, if you don't post your html code, how did we know how to change your ui?

Answer (score 1):

From http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu:

```
Methods:
   refresh
       parses the original element again, updates the value option and
       rerenders the menu triggers events if value changed
```

So just add that after making the changes to the underlying selects:

```
$(function(){
    $('a#switchButton').click(function(){
        var $sel1 = $('#fromCurrency');
        var val1 = $sel1.val();
        var $sel2 = $('#toCurrency');
        var val2 = $sel2.val();
        $sel1.find("option[value='"+val1+"']").attr("selected",false);
        $sel1.find("option[value='"+val2+"']").attr("selected",true);
        $sel2.find("option[value='"+val2+"']").attr("selected",false);
        $sel2.find("option[value='"+val1+"']").attr("selected",true);

        $sel1.selectmenu('refresh');
        $sel2.selectmenu('refresh');

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: try forcing a rebuild by doing `$sel1.selectmenu('refresh', true);` and the same for `$sel2`